# creating metapackages

Tags: aptitude, dpkg

got some problems while creating metapackages

tried to create a meta package containing forensic toolkits, on ubuntu i even got problems creating an *.deb file. 
 dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no orig.tar file found dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source
-b forensics-0.1 gave error exit status 255*

later i tried it using debian 5, creating the deb works, but there i got into some problems with Depends

```
debian:/home/matthias/Desktop/meta# dpkg --install *.deb
Wähle vormals abgewähltes Paket meta.
(Lese Datenbank ... 96897 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entpacke meta (aus meta_0.1-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von meta:
 meta hängt ab von python (>= 2.6.6-2); aber:
  Version von python auf dem System ist 2.5.2-3.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von meta (--install):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - lasse es unkonfiguriert
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 meta
```

the file control looks like this:

```
Source: meta
Section: unknown
Priority: extra
Maintainer: root <matthias@schrattenholzer.at>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7)
Standards-Version: 3.7.3
Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>
Package: meta
Architecture: any
Depends: python (>= 2.6.6-2)
Description: short description
 forensic toolkits
```

any ideas?

kind regards

Comment: Although most of us are familiar with the output of dpkg, i think you may benefit from setting LC_ALL to en_US before posting excerpts from the shell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOW TO create a DEBIAN META-PACKAGE

```
$ mkdir -p ~/packages/<package-name>/DEBIAN 
$ cd ~/packages/<package-name>/DEBIAN
$ touch postinst
$ touch control
```

example of an control file:

```
Package: forensic-tool-collection
Version: 0.1
Section: main
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Depends: python-pyside, sleuthkit, dcfldd, python-elixir, python-urwid, python-imaging, libsvn-java, python-qt4, autopsy, xfce4-xkb-plugin, python-poppler, python-magic, libpoppler-qt4-dev, poppler-utils, python-mpmath, python-matplotlib, python-scitools, audacity, mediainfo, mediainfo-gui, octave, octave-image, qtoctave, octave-signal, pdftk, disktype, scalpel, uudeview, python-opencv, ewf-tools, xmount, testdisk, parted, outguess, avidemux, aimage, afflib-tools, icocom, wine, readpst, libimage-exiftool-perl, hexedit, steghide, fotoxx, serna, antiword, hdparm, python-setuptools, python-elixir, python-dev, python2.6-dev
Installed-Size:
Maintainer: 4en'sicks 
Description: collection of forensic-tools
```

postinst file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinstall script for forensic toll collection
# 
# see: dh_installdeb(1)
set -e

case "$1" in 
configure)
## pherhaps something has to be changed in future 
echo "Congrats..."
;;

abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
;;

*)
echo "postinst called with unknown argument `$1'" > &2
exit1
;;
esac

#DEBHELPER

exit 0
```

next steps:

```
$ cd ~/packages/
$ chmod 555 forensic/DEBIAN/postinst
$ dpkg-deb -b forensic forensic.deb
```

installation:

```
$ dpkg -i forensic.deb
$ apt-get -f install
```

Comment: It means, we can't include version information on the depends list of meta package

Answer (score 0):

On Debian there is a package called 'equivs' that should exist on Ubuntu too. Equivs sole purpose is to assist in creating meta packages or empty packages to meet a dependency you don't want to install.

To use it run equivs-control filename, and it will create a template file named filename. Edit filename to change the details. Finally run equivs-build filename to create the package and then install it.

Comment: SOLVED installation: